# Change title of the Ant Design table depending on state value

Tags: reactjs, state, antd

I need a bit of help here, In an Ant Design table, I need the title of a table should change depending on the state value. In the given sandbox example the column title `surname` should change to `Second Name` where the switch in on, else it should show `surname` only.

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-sun-1rtz1?file=/index.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change title based on `surNameShow`

```
render() {
    const { dataSource, surNameShow } = this.state;
    const columns = this.columns;
    // check and set title here
    // If you want to change the second column you can use index 1, if you want it to be dynamic just loop through columns array update column you desire
    if (surNameShow) {
      columns[1].title = "Second Name";
    } else {
      columns[1].title = "Surname";
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="mr-3"> Change Surname to Second Name</p>
        <Switch onChange={() => this.handleChnage()} />
        <Table
          bordered
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={columns}
          pagination={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-blackburn-xunbm?file=/index.js:891-1409)